# Mapping over second array in JSX

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I am currently mapping over some data in order to render 4 dots on a status bar in the JSX in React Native. However, I have a second array that I would like to map over, so that each date appears where i have the comment ***need dates to go here*** , so that the dates go below each dot that is rendered.

I am mapping over them below that comment, but I need them to go above as part of the first map. Is there a way to go about this?

```
const StatusBar = ({ projectData }) => {

  const statusBarPositions = [1, 2, 3];
  const currentStatusBarPosition = () => {
    let position;

    switch (projectData.get('state')) {
      case 'Project 1':
        position = 1;

        break;
      case 'Project 2':
        position = 2;
        break;
      case 'Project 3':
        position = 3;
        break;
      default:
        position = 0;
    }

    return position;
  };

  const projectDates = ['12/1', '3/1', '6/1', '9/1']

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={ styles.statusBarContainer }>
        <View style={ styles.progressDotFirst } />
        {
          statusBarPositions.map((statusBarPosition) => {
            return (
              <View key={ statePosition } style={ styles.statusBarLineContainer }>
                <View style={ (currentStatusBarPosition() >= statusBarPosition) ? [styles.statusBarLine, styles.statusBarActive] : styles.statusBarLine } />
                <View style={ (currentStatusBarPosition() >= statusBarPosition) ? [styles.statusBarDot, styles.statusBarActive] : styles.statusBarDot } />
              </View>
              <View>
                <Text>{ ***need dates to go here*** }</Text>
              </View>
            );
          })
        }
      </View>
      <View>
        {
          projectDates.map((date) => {
            return (
              <Text>{ date }</Text>
            )
          })

        }
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

StatusBar.propTypes = {
  projectData: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object)
};

export default statusBar;
```

Comment: Are both arrays in sync index-wise? In other words, does `projectDates[i] correspond to `statusBarPositions[i]`'s date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes the array index as the 2nd argument. If both arrays correspond to each other index-wise, then you can use that to render the dates (note the index `i` in `statusBarPositions.map((statusBarPosition, i)`):

```
<View style={ styles.progressDotFirst } />
{
    statusBarPositions.map((statusBarPosition, i) => {
    return (
        <View key={ statePosition } style={ styles.statusBarLineContainer }>
        <View style={ (currentStatusBarPosition() >= statusBarPosition) ? [styles.statusBarLine, styles.statusBarActive] : styles.statusBarLine } />
        <View style={ (currentStatusBarPosition() >= statusBarPosition) ? [styles.statusBarDot, styles.statusBarActive] : styles.statusBarDot } />
        </View>
        <View>
        <Text>{ projectDates[i] }</Text>
        </View>
    );
    })
}
</View>
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please don't forget to upvote and accept as answer!